# Installing scott schema for oracle 11g express

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, oracle-xe

I want to install scott schema, a sample database in oracle.

But in express edition, I can't find out it.

Please help me install it on Oracle 11g express.

I'm a newbie, pls help me

Comment: I Googled and came up with this: http://code.google.com/p/adf-samples-demos/downloads/detail?name=demoscripts.zip&can=2&q=

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact I too came here to build a sample DB for scott schema in Oracle_v11g. I couldn't find DBCA as told above, but on further search, I found a file called scott.sql. It had lines to create the needed DB. So I connected to Oracle as system and ran it - all the tables were created. Now I couldn't connect using Scott as Id. Changed the password in System schema:

```
alter user scott identified by tiger;
```

Now I could login and access the needed tables from scott. Hope anyone looking for this might find this info useful.

Answer (score 2):

when you are installing oracle database you can install all oracle example schemas like scott, HR, oe ... 
you can install these in step "Specify Database Config Details".click the last tab page "Sample Schemas" then check the check box "create database with sample schemas" as displayed bellow in screenshot.

if you already installed database you can recreate it for training "without uninstalling it" by write the command:
start -> run -> dbca
to run oracle database configuration assistant.
follow steps to drop your running database and recreate it with sample schemas.

[image]

### update

and here in Oracle 12C:

[image]

Comment: Command dbca not working. I'm using express version

Comment: check this link http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17781_01/doc.112/e18644/get_start.htm#BABGAFBD